# Updating old swift programming project, what would cause the error: "Value of type '[ToDoItem]' has no member 'removeAtIndex'"

Tags: ios, swift

New to swift programming and have run into the error:

`"Value of type '[ToDoItem]' has no member 'removeAtIndex'"`

for this code block:

````
func toDoItemDeleted(toDoItem: ToDoItem) {
  let index = (toDoItems as NSArray).indexOfObject(toDoItem)
  if index == NSNotFound { return }

  // could removeAtIndex in the loop but keep it here for when indexOfObject works
  toDoItems.removeAtIndex(index)

  // use the UITableView to animate the removal of this row
  tableView.beginUpdates()
  let indexPathForRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
  tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathForRow], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
  tableView.endUpdates()    
} ```

This is old code that was used from this website: ```https://www.raywenderlich.com/2153-how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1-2
````

Is the function removeAtIndex deprecated?

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: `toDoItems.remove(at: index)`

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks! This fixed it. Please don't take this as rude, but am also getting an error now for ```tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathForRow], withRowAnimation: .Fade)``` the error reads: "Cannot convert value of type 'NSIndexPath' to expected element type 'Array<IndexPath>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'IndexPath')" Please any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like there's already an answer that addresses this. With Swift code this old, you'll run into a lot of issues like this. Back in the older transition days, there would be helper functions from the compiler to guide you through the transitions, but the ones this old have been removed.

Comment: @jnpdx Got it! Probably should find a better tut than raywenderlich's because some seem so outdated that they aren't that useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Swift 2 code, outdated for many years.

Nowadays you can write it *dramatically* shorter

```
func deleteTodoItem(_ toDoItem: ToDoItem) {
   guard let index = toDoItems.firstIndex(of: toDoItem) else { return }
   toDoItems.remove(at: index)
   tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .fade)
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! where do you recommend to go for learning swift?

Comment: Actually Ray Wenderlich is a quite good source, although there are a few outdated articles. For the basics I recommend Apple's Swift Language Guide and also its tutorials. See https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training

Comment: Yeah I liked the layout just some are dated! Thanks for the help!